# Using AG-Grid , Angular and TypeScript how to set the Column ColSpan dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Given the row data as follows :

```
rowData = [ 
    { field_1 : value_1_1 , field_2 : value_1_2 , colSpan : 1 } , 
    { field_1 : value_2_1 , colSpan : 2} , 
    { field_1 : value_3_1 , field_2 : value_3_2 , colSpan : 1} 
];
```

Column definitions as follows :

```
columnDefs = [ 
    {
        header  : field_1_name , 
        field   : field_1 , 
        colSpan : getColSpan(params) 
    } , 
    {   
        header : field_2_name , 
        field  : field_2  
    } 
];
```

For the getColSpan fucntion , what TypeScript syntax can be used to implement the pseudo snippet below ? :

```
getColSpan(params) 

    return colSpan value for each row
```

The resulting grid should be as below :
[image: see screenshot here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the demo example [Simple Column Spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-spanning/#example-column-spanning-simple), you can have `colSpan` function as below to get the result you're expecting.

```
{
    header  : field_1_name, 
    field   : field_1,
    colSpan : function(params) {
      var value = params.data.field_1;
      if (value === "value_2_1") {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
}
```